# How to decode web scraped data..?

Tags: python, web-scraping, text-mining

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from urllib2 import urlopen as uo
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib2 import Request as ur
import numpy as np
from pandas import ExcelWriter
url = 'https://navbharattimes.indiatimes.com/movie-masti/movie-review/village-rockstars-movie-review-in-hindi/moviereview/65997258.cms'
        
request=ur(url,None,headers)
uC = uo(request)
html_read = uC.read()
uC.close()
html_soup = soup(html_read, 'lxml')
review = html_soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'Normal')
review
```

After running above web scraper code i get following code instead of original text output..My Question is how to convert this ascii code into text.

Here it is webscraper data.:-

```
\u0930\u0947\u0923\u0941\u0915\u093e \u0935\u094d\u092f\u0935\u0939\u093e\u0930\u0947<br/>\u0915\u0939\u093e\u0928\u0940:</strong> \u0905\u0938\u092e \u0915\u0947 \u090f\u0915 \u0916\u0942\u092c\u0938\u0942\u0930\u0924 \u0917\u093e\u0902\u0935 \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u0930\u0939\u0928\u0947 \u0935\u093e\u0932\u0940 \u0927\u0941\u0928\u0942 \u0915\u094b \u092a\u0947\u0921\u093c \u092a\u0930 \u091a\u0922\u093c\u0928\u093e, \u0932\u0921\u093c\u0915\u094b\u0902 \u0915\u0947 \u0938\u093e\u0925 \u0916\u0947\u0932\u0928\u093e \u0914\u0930 \u0905\u092a\u0928\u093e \u0925\u0930\u092e\u093e\u0915\u0949\u0932 \u0915\u093e \u0917\u093f\u091f\u093e\u0930 \u092b\u094d\u0932\u0949\u0928\u094d\u091f \u0915\u0930\u0928\u093e \u0915\u093e\u092b\u0940 \u0905\u091a\u094d\u091b\u093e \u0932\u0917\u0924\u093e \u0939\u0948\u0964 \u0935\u0939 \u0918\u0930 \u0915\u0947 \u0915\u093e\u092e\u094b\u0902 \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u0905\u092a\u0928\u0940 \u0935\u093f\u0927\u0935\u093e \u092e\u093e\u0902 \u0915\u093e \u0939\u093e\u0925 \u092d\u0940 \u092c\u091f\u093e\u0924\u0940 \u0939\u0948\u0964 \u0909\u0938\u0915\u093e \u0938\u092a\u0928\u093e \u0939\u0948 \u0915\u093f \u090f\u0915 \u0926\u093f\u0928 \u0909\u0938\u0915\u0947 \u092a\u093e\u0938 \u0905\u0938\u0932 \u0917\u093f\u091f\u093e\u0930 \u0939\u094b\u0964 \u0915\u094d\u092f\u093e \u0909\u0938\u0915\u093e \u092f\u0939 \u0938\u092a\u0928\u093e \u092a\u0942\u0930\u093e \u0939\u094b \u092a\u093e\u090f\u0917\u093e
```

Comment: Please add tag specifying Python version.

Answer (score 1):

You've got `Unicode`. To see what was retrieved try:

```
print review
```

This will produce something like:

```
रेणुका व्यवहारेकहानी: असम के एक खूबसूरत गांव में रहने वाली धुनू को पेड़ पर चढ़ना, लड़कों के साथ खेलना और अपना थरमाकॉल का गिटार फ्लॉन्ट करना काफी अच्छा लगता है। वह घर के कामों में अपनी विधवा मां का हाथ भी बटाती है। उसका सपना है कि एक दिन उसके पास असल गिटार हो। क्या उसका यह सपना पूरा हो पाएगा
```

Answer (score 0):

This is unicode data, not ascii.
and will have to be encoded and displayed appropriately.

- python3 has better support for unicode, consider switching if you aren't already using it.
- the terminal where you are running it should also be capable of handling / displaying unicode data, otherwise you would see boxes where characters should be.

---

edit: the text is in hindi, in order to be able to display it properly, the fonts will also have to be installed on your system.

---

edit: here is my attempt at scraping the same content using python3:

```
In [1]: import requests 
   ...: from lxml import etree 
   ...:  
   ...: url = 'https://navbharattimes.indiatimes.com/movi
   ...: e-masti/movie-review/village-rockstars-movie-revi
   ...: ew-in-hindi/moviereview/65997258.cms' 
   ...:  
   ...: r = requests.get(url) 
   ...: tree = etree.HTML(r.text) 
   ...:  
   ...: all_divs = tree.xpath('//div[@class="Normal"]//te
   ...: xt()') 
   ...:  
   ...: text = ' '.join([i for i in all_divs if i.strip()
   ...: !=""]) 
   ...:                                                  

In [2]: text                                             
Out[2]: "रेणुका व्यवहारे कहानी:  असम के एक खूबसूरत गांव में रहने वाली धुनू को पेड़ पर चढ़ना, लड़कों के साथ खेलना और अपना थरमाकॉल का गिटार फ्लॉन्ट करना काफी अच्छा लगता है। वह घर के कामों में अपनी विधवा मां का हाथ भी बटाती है। उसका सपना है कि एक दिन उसके पास असल गिटार हो। क्या उसका यह सपना पूरा हो पाएगा?\n रिव्यू:  लेखक-प्रड्यूसर-निर्देशक  रीमा दास  की असमी फिल्म ' विलेज रॉकस्टार्स ' भारत की ओर से ऑस्कर 2019 के लिए बेस्ट फॉरेन लैंग्वेज कैटिगरी के लिए भेजी गई है। यह आशाओं, इच्छाओं और कठिनाइयों के सामने निडरता की बेबाक कहानी है जो स्लो होने के बावजूद आपकी कल्पनाओं को बांधती है। यह एक तरह से रीमा की अपने घर और वहां के खूबसूरत लोगों के लिए भेंट है। जिन लोगों को धीमी चलने वाली कहानियां पसंद नहीं हैं, यहां उनके सब्र की परीक्षा हो सकती है लेकिन रीमा ने अपने अंदाज में सभी किरदारों और उनकी जिंदगी का विवरण देने में समय लिया है। असम के दृश्यों और वहां की धुनों की शानदार सिनेमटॉग्रफी और ऑडियोग्रफी के जरिए रीमा आपको धुनू के सपनों की दुनिया में ले जाती हैं। \n एक ऐसी दुनिया जो आपको आपके सौभाग्य का एहसास दिलाती है। एक ऐसी दुनिया जहां अपने दुर्भाग्य के बावजूद एक मां अपनी बेटी को आगे बढ़ने के लिए प्रेरित करती है। वह कहती है कि हमारे पास परिश्रम के अलावा कुछ नहीं है। \n यह फिल्म गरीबी और उससे होने वाली दुविधाओं को दर्शाती है। इसका थीम ट्रैजडी है लेकिन फिर भी यह खुशियों को ढूंढने की एक दिल छू लेने वाली कहानी है। \n शानदार विजुअल और इमोशन्स के अलावा रीमा का लेखन भी काफी अच्छा है जिसमें लैंगिक समानता को बड़े ही अच्छे तरीके से कहानी में मिला दिया गया है। धुनू की मां अपनी बेटी की परवरिश बेटे की तरह ही करती है। वह धुनू का साथ देती है और उसे 'लड़की की तरह' रहने की नसीहत देने वाले समाज से लड़ती भी है। फिल्म की महिलाएं उन्हीं सामाजिक, शारीरिक और मानसिक समस्याओं से जूझती हैं जिनसे दो जून की रोटी कमाने के लिए एक पुरुष जूझता है। \n विलेज रॉकस्टार्स आपको एक ही समय में रुलाती भी है और उत्साहित भी करती है। यह एक छोटी बच्ची और उसकी मां के तकलीफों की कहानी से ज्यादा उन तकलीफों से लड़ने के जज्बे की कहानी है।\n ट्रेलर: X"
```